# Using Mouse Wheel into the Memo Box or Combo Box in Access Forms

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access form named "NewStaff" that contains a Memo box. When I clicked inside it, rolling the mouse wheel would cause an exit to this field and it would not be placed on the text inside the Memo box. Finally, I put the following code on the ***MouseWheel Event*** form and now I can move the Memo box lines by rolling the mouse wheel.

> ```
>  Private Sub Form_MouseWheel(ByVal Page As Boolean, ByVal Count As Long)
>          Dim i As Long
>          Dim s As String
>          If Me.ActiveControl.Name = "ُNewStaff" Then
>              If Count > 0 Then
>                  For i = 1 To Count
>                      s = s & "{DOWN}"
>                  Next i
>              Else
>                  For i = 1 To -Count
>                      s = s & "{UP}"
>                  Next i
>              End If
>              SendKeys s
>          End If
>  End Sub
> ```

The problem is that **the cursor has jumping three lines to three lines** and **finally leaves the field!**

Is there a way to go line by line and stay in Memo box for the cursor? ... Thanks

Comment: Move the cursor word by word?

Comment: No, when you rolling the mouse wheel, usually it move up or down. I mean, one line to up or one line to down. But this code that I wrote moves the cursor three line by three lines!!  This issue need to solve. but I don't know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `SendKeys UP/DOWN` to scroll is clunky - users don't necessarily want the cursor to move, only the text to scroll. Plus the "sudden exit" effect you noticed.

A long time ago I found and adapted this solution.
Paste all the code into a module, and call it as shown in the comments.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Const WM_VSCROLL = &H115
Private Const SB_LINEUP = 0
Private Const SB_LINEDOWN = 1

Public Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
   Alias "SendMessageA" _
   (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
   ByVal wMsg As Long, _
   ByVal wParam As Long, _
   LParam As Any) _
   As Long
   
Private Declare Function apiGetFocus Lib "user32" _
        Alias "GetFocus" _
         () As Long
'

' Scroll multi-line textboxes with the mouse wheel. The textbox must have the focus.
'
' Call this sub in the MouseWheel event of the form(s) containing multi-line textboxes, like this:
'
' Private Sub Form_MouseWheel(ByVal Page As Boolean, ByVal Count As Long)
'    Call MouseWheelScroll(Count)
' End Sub
'
' Sources
' http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=195679
' http://www.extramiledata.com/scroll-microsoft-access-text-box-using-mouse-wheel/

Public Sub MouseWheelScroll(ByVal Count As Long)

    Dim LinesToScroll As Integer
    Dim hwndActiveControl As Long
    
    If Screen.ActiveControl.Properties.Item("ControlType") = acTextBox Then
        hwndActiveControl = fhWnd(Screen.ActiveControl)
        For LinesToScroll = 1 To Abs(Count)
            SendMessage hwndActiveControl, WM_VSCROLL, IIf(Count < 0, SB_LINEUP, SB_LINEDOWN), 0&
        Next
    End If

End Sub

' Source: http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0027.htm
' Code Courtesy of Dev Ashish

Private Function fhWnd(ctl As Control) As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ' We only use this function for Screen.ActiveControl, so this is not necessary.
    ' I can't remember if I found it harmful in some situations.
    ' ctl.SetFocus
    
    fhWnd = apiGetFocus
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, but I couldn't test your code because VBA stops it and shows a message that this code is not for 64-bit system!

Comment: Update:

I added a "PtrSafe" after Declare for making compatible with 64bit. I test your code and it's works fine perfectly! Thanks again dear Andre

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's a mouse setting:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, **I found a solution to one of the problems**. The problem of jumping **"three lines to three lines"** in the mouse settings (Mouse Properties) was in the Windows Control Panel, which by default is on the number three. We have to change it to number one!

**Path: Control Panel > Mouse Properties > Wheel**

[image: Go to: Control Panel > Mouse Properties > Wheel]

**Now, We just have to fix the sudden exit from the Memo box!**